# Update GitHub file content with requests API

Tags: python, git, github, python-requests, github-actions

I am trying to update an existing file in GitHub with Python. I am using sample code shown below. I am referring to [this document](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28).

Following challenges are coming:

1. It is showing status code 201 and showing workflow execution from main branch, however it should push code in branch "branch-1"
2. I am getting code 201, if a new file is mention in path, if I mentions an existing file then I get 422 status code. What to do for updating a file?
3. What is the event? How this can be captured by GitHub workflow?

```
payload = '{"branch ": "branch-1",  "message":"my commit message ","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}'

path  = "test6.txt?ref=branch-1"

r = requests.put(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}'.format(
    owner=owner, repo=repo, path=path),
    headers={
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
        'authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
            },
    data = payload

    )


print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: The branch is specified in the payload. If not specified, the default branch of the repository is used.

Comment: I did specified branch in payload, still it is hitting or executing workflow of main

Comment: In `"branch ": "branch-1"`, is the space after `branch` a typo in this question or did you write so in your code?

Comment: Yes that was mistake in code as well. Thanks I found out this after your first comment.